# How to load a jQuery.DataTables grid with dynamic JSON data

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, datatables

I'm trying to load some simple JSON data into a jQuery.DataTables (datatables.net), The grid is showing up as it is defined in the HTML, but does not change based on the new data.

**What am I missing? any suggestion?**

HTML:

```
<table id="example" class="display" style="width:100%;">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Id</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td>0</td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

JavaScript: (jQuery and jQuery.DataTables are loaded)

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#example").DataTable({
        data: [{ Id: "1" }, { Id: "2" }],
        columns: { data: "Id", title: "ID" }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, the my code for injecting the JSON data (or as a variable) is fine, the problem was another click event for the grid that I forgot I added before the initialization of that grid (bad bad me)

```
$("#example " + "tbody").on("click", "tr", function () {
var data = table.row(this).data();
isDebug && console.log('You clicked on ' + data[0] + '\'s row');
isDebug && console.log(data);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Your column data should be set of Array. Something like this

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#example").DataTable({
        data: [{ Id: "1" }, { Id: "2" }],
        columns: [{ data: "Id", title: "ID" }]
    });
});
```

For Dynamic Data using ajax

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#example').DataTable( {
        "ajax": "data/objects.txt",
        "columns": [
            { "data": "name" },
            { "data": "position" },
            { "data": "office" },
            { "data": "extn" },
            { "data": "start_date" },
            { "data": "salary" }
        ]
    } );
} );
```

JSON txt file

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "id": "1",
      "name": "Tiger Nixon",
      "position": "System Architect",
      "salary": "$320,800",
      "start_date": "2011/04/25",
      "office": "Edinburgh",
      "extn": "5421"
    },
    {
      "id": "2",
      "name": "Garrett Winters",
      "position": "Accountant",
      "salary": "$170,750",
      "start_date": "2011/07/25",
      "office": "Tokyo",
      "extn": "8422"
    }
  ]
}
```

More detail [Here](http://%20https://datatables.net/examples/ajax/objects.html)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
  var options = {
        data: [{ Id: "1" }, { Id: "2" }],
        columns: { data: "Id", title: "ID" }
    }
   var dataTable =  $("#example").DataTable(options );

   // Reload and refresh
   dataTable.draw();
```